# Making status visible in main form from another form

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have multiple forms based application in that I have some entry forms, if in entry form filled and submit button clicked then I want to display submitting status in main form status-strip

I used like this but not working

```
Main status = new Main();
status.workStatusStrip.Text = "Submitted Successfully";
```

sample code preferred..

Comment: "but not working" is a very poor problem description. Can you explain _exactly_ what is not working? What do you expect to happen? What isn't happening? Any exceptions? Errors? What happens when you debug through?

Comment: i want to display a status on main form (which already opened) from another form  thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good old static globals (remember vb?)

```
WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Label statusMessageLabel;
    public static string StatusText { set { statusMessageLabel.Text = value; } }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        statusMessageLabel = label1;

        // from anywhere ->
        Form1.StatusText = "a message";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Main status = new Main();
```

Creates a *new* `Main` form, not your original form (and you don't see it as you don't `Show()` it).

You need a reference to the original `Main` form before you can set properties on it, though doing so will cause coupling between your different forms (not a good thing).

One way to achieve what you want is to have an event handler on the second form that fires when the button is clicked and subscribe to it from the `Main` form, where you would set the status.

Comment: i want to display status in status Strip in main form

Comment: @user836890 - Yes, but you need to understand the difference between a class and an instance. When newing up a `Main` form, you are creating an instance if it (and you might have several instances).

Comment: OK OK i got you, i am new to c# that's why.. please can you give me code for what i want